# Next JS api : TypeError: res.redirect is not a function

Tags: node.js, next.js

I'm trying to do something which seems very easy but I didn't found on the web why do I get this issue.

I'm trying to implement an API route in my Next JS app. In this route, I want to make a redirection to another web page (I chose google to check if it works).
I looked at the NextJS documentation : https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/response-helpers

and I try to reproduct the redirection, as below :

inside pages/api/paiement-accepte.js :

```
export default function handler(req, res) {
  res.redirect(200, "http://www.google.com")
}
```

But when I go on http://localhost:3000/api/paiement-accepte I only get an Internal Server Error

And my node logs tells me :
"TypeError: res.redirect is not a function"

Do you have any idea of what's going on and what should I do to make it working ?

Comment: `res.redirect` should definitely work in API routes. What version of Next.js are you using?

Comment: I'm using the 9.3.5 next version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all those who are currently experiencing this problem. Here is the solution I have put in place :

```
res.writeHead(302, {
    Location: "http://www.google.com",
    //add other headers here...
  })
```

I still don't know why res.redirect didn't work but this did the job.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/redirect

```
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';

let url = 'https://codingmstr.com'
redirect(url);
```